# Can't figure out why int(" ") is acting weird

Tags: python, int, valueerror

So i'm making a code that takes a name and number from a user and then counts to it by ones.  I'm using 'while' and 'try' to stop any non letters from going through, but it doesn't seem to work with just blank.  I've used idle to test if "int("")" and it comes up with a value error, but for some reason when its in a function it is acting up.  Any ideas?  I left out the rest of the code to just this.

Here's my code.

```
testNumber=""

def numQualify(x):
     while x:
         try:
             x=int(x)
         except ValueError:
             print("That was not a proper number.")
             return False
         else:
             print("Great number!")
             break

testNumber=input("Write a number")

while numQualify(testNumber) == False:
    testNumber=input("Please try another number")

print("Done")
```

Comment: Your code is a bit messy, but it seems to work for me? On what input is it failing?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about the blank input, thought you meant space. Answering now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, some things implicitly count as `False` for the purpose of a conditional like a `while` loop or `if` statement. The empty string is one of those things. So, when you pass the empty string into `numQualify`, the `while x` loop immediately terminates, and since there is no return statement, it returns `None`, and `None != False`.

You don't actually need a while loop though! `x` never changes during numQualify. You can actually simplify `numQualify` quite a bit:

```
def numQualify(x):
    try:
        int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("That was not a proper number.")
        return False
    print("Great number!")
    return True
```

Now the empty string enters the try block, and so has no issues. Because you have your `while numQualify(testNumber) == False:` loop, you have no need for a loop inside of `numQualify`

Comment: The considering of values as representing `True` and `False` is often called its [truthiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness)—a fairly recently coined term.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh okay, that makes a lot of sense.  I had been having trouble with this for a while!  Thank you so much, appreciate the quick response.